# Trying to determine when an async job is complete: Calling Oracle's dbms_job.submit

Tags: oracle

Please consider the following execution sequence:

Execute the following query to get the last time that a materilized view of interest was rebuilt and store this isn a local variable, "lv_prior_mv_rfrsh_dt":

```
SELECT NVL(mv.last_refresh_end_time, sysdate) INTO lv_prior_mv_rfrsh_dt from all_mviews where mview_name = 'MY_MV";
```

We then execute the following code to submit a DBMS job to execute an application procedure, "Do_mv_refresh".

```
 dbms_job.submit(job => l_jobid, what => 'MySchema.MyPkg.Do_mv_refresh('''
                                                    || p_user
                                                    || ''', '''
                                                    || p_cm_r_pm
                                                    || ''');');
```

Within the `Do_MV_Refresh` procedure, a call is made to `dba_proc.mview_refresh` to refresh the materialized "My_MV".

I believe that execution of `dba_proc.mview_refresh` is asynchronous, so the thread of execution continues:

In the following code, a loop has been established as follows:

```
BEGIN LOOP

  dbms_lock.sleep(180);
  
  SELECT mv.last_refresh_end_time INTO lv_POST_mv_rfrsh_dt from all_mviews where mview_name = 'MY_MV";
   
   IF lv_post_mv_rfrsh_dt IS NOT NULL AND lv_post_mv_rfrsh_dt > lv_prior_mv_rfrsh_dt THEN              
        EXIT;
   END IF;
                    
END LOOP
```

Do you expect that this code will properly loop until the MV is built or so you think the query that populates `lv_POST_mv_rfrsh_dt` will always be hung waiting for the MV job to complete before it is able to return the query result? If it will be hung, are we in danger of a timeout?

I don't have access to an environment with enough data to test this but in a dev environment the query to populate the lv_POST_mv_rfrsh_dt variable appears to be hung waiting the completion of the rebuilding of the MV.

**Update:**
How do I determine the MV Refresh job that was submitted failed? Will the all_mviews.last_refresh_end_time be updated? I would expect  this to only be updated if it succeeds. How do we prevent an infinite loop if it fails? When I select * from dba_jobs I see no records. When is this view cleared?

Comment: Could you explain the reason, why you want to wait until the end of a job you started asynchronously with `dbms_job`?  Or in other word if you want to *wait* why don't you simple call a `DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH` which is *synchronous* so you'll get the controll back after the MV is refreshed.

Comment: @Marmite Thanks for the reply. I am trying to understand the code, but I believe the answer is that there is shared code between a web app and a batch process. The web app wants to initiate the process and return control to the web but the batch process wants to make use of the web of code and call the same existing code but use it synchronously by establishing a loop to simulate a synchronous call. I know that sounds bad but refactoring all of this code would be a serious effort so I am trying  to minimize changes.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the `all_mviews` query to block while the materialized view is refreshing.  You might be in danger of a timeout if the client application sets a timeout.  If there is an error refreshing the materialized view, I'd expect that this would go into an infinite loop (at least until the error was corrected and the refresh was rerun).  But I wouldn't guarantee any of these things because I haven't personally tested them.

Comment: I don't think what you think is going on is really going on. `all_mviews` will not be locked when an mview is refreshing. Even if another transaction had a row lock on that particular mview to update it, it wouldn't block your select. "Writers never block readers" is one of the advantages of Oracle.

Comment: @ealoson. When I ran in an env that had more data and the rebuild took longer, I was able to query the MV w/o block. Not sure why it seemed to be clocked in our lower env where it took 60 secs to rebuild. I expected that the MV start  time would have been updated with the start time when the refresh began and the end time set to null, but it looks like other are updated together, which was a little surprising,

Comment: Please see my **Update** in the original question